# Emum not assigning values

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, enums

I have an enum class and I declare it as such for a state machine and declare a class as such

```
#file name is statefm.py
class State(Enum):
    START = auto
    MID = auto
    END = auto

class gate:

    def __init__(self):
        self.st = State.START
        self.counter = 0
        self.done = False
    def test(self):
        print(self.st)
        self.st = State.MID
        print(self.st)
        self.state = State.END
        print(self.st)
```

Then in another file, I do the necessary import, instantiate an object of the class and call the test class method,

```
import statefm

k = statefm.gate()
k.test()
```

Oddly, this is the output I get.

```
State.START
State.START
State.START
```

I also call list and all I get from list is just the first enum element in two places. Can I please get any help on this?

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't `self.state = State.END` be `self.st = State.END`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to call it like `auto()`, not `auto`

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class State(Enum):
    START = auto()
    MID = auto()
    END = auto()
```

That using the bare name `auto` works at all is kind of a funny accident. All values just get aliased to the same class `auto` itself, and your resulting enumeration type actually only has one member, `State.START`, with two more aliases pointing to the same member.

```
>>> State.__members__
mappingproxy({'START': <State.START: <class 'enum.auto'>>,
              'MID': <State.START: <class 'enum.auto'>>,
              'END': <State.START: <class 'enum.auto'>>})
>>> len(State)
1
```